# iOS - App crashing, but not generating crash report

Tags: ios, xcode

My iOS Application Extension is crashing sporadically in ways that I'm unable to replicate or even begin to figure out how to replicate. When I go into XCode and go to `Window->Devices->View Device Logs` it's not showing any crashes for my application. I have no way to debug what's going on without these crash logs.

Is there a reason that they might not be generating?

I've tested across three devices:

- iPhone 6S running iOS 11.1
- iPhone 7 running iOS 10
- iPhone 7 running iOS 11

I'm getting the same result on all of them. The extension will randomly crash during the day, and when I notice that it has crashed and plug it in to recover crash logs, there is nothing there.

I'm positive that it is a crash and that the extension isn't just closing. Right before this started happening I was getting several common crashes that I had reports for, but then this started happening and I"m no longer able to verify which of my crashes are still happening at all.

Are there common reasons that this might be happening?

Comment: hi, did you get any solution ?
I am facing same, app crashing but not generating crash log on iphone XR (ios: 13.4).
please helps me.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are supposed to check your scheme. edit scheme -> info - build configuration -> debug, just as the below image

[image: edit scheme]